# iOS use of custom Container View Controller

Tags: ios, containers, addsubview

I try to use an `UIViewController` as an custom ContainerViewController to show certain ViewControllers with custom behavior. I have an `UIView` "detailsView" property in my ContainerViewController to show the content of the loaded ViewControllers. The problem is that the loaded controller is shown but without any content like buttons. What do I do wrong?

part of my ContainerViewContoller.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *detailsView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;
```

the `viewDidLoad` method of my ContainerViewContoller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 NSLog(@"called");

 SWResultViewController *swResultViewController = [[SWResultViewController alloc]init];
 self.currentViewController = swResultViewController;

 // this line doesn't help to show the buttons
 swResultViewController.view.frame = self.detailsView.bounds;

 [self addChildViewController: self.currentViewController];
 [self.detailsView addSubview: self.currentViewController.view];
 [self.currentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

should be shown:____________________________________is shown:

[image] ___________ [image]

Comment: You know that UIViewController has a view property that has to be set...

Comment: Hello rocky, thanks for the answer. How and where do I set the property? Are you talking about the `detailsView` in the ContainerViewController?

Comment: When I try `swResultViewController.view.frame = self.detailsView.bounds;` in `ViewDidLoad` nothing is changing. I don"t understand that the color gradient from the `SWResultViewController` is shown but no other content like the button?